# How to check a string for partial match and if matched convert string to a pre-defined value

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am importing 1000's of vehicles into my Woocommerce site that are being imported via XML feeds from multiple different dealer websites.

Each dealer uses their own naming convention for "Colors" so we end up with a huge amount of color variations that are unnecessary. Before I process their feed into our site I'm running the function below to convert their colors to ours.

In my example code below you can see I have several "blue" variations such as Blueberry, Blue Fire, Blue Metallic, etc.

I have been using the code below and converting the dealer color to my color but it's not efficient for me to keep updating the list every time a dealer adds a new color or enters a typo.

How can I modify this code so it doesn't check for exact match but instead looks for my root word (blue) in the dealer color and if it finds a string with blue in it anywhere it automatically assigns it a new vale of just my color "Blue".

```
<?php
function my_color($value) {
  $color = array(
    '60Th Anniversary Yellow' => 'Yellow',
    'Alpine White' => 'White',
    'Aluminum' => 'Silver',
    'Aqua' => 'Blue',
    'Bk' => 'Black',
    'Black' => 'Black',
    'Black Cherry' => 'Black',
    'Black Denim' => 'Black',
    'Black Metallic' => 'Black',
    'Black Pearl' => 'Black',
    'Black Pearl Metallic' => 'Black',
    'Black Satin' => 'Black',
    'Black-Deluxe' => 'Black',
    'Blaze Orange' => 'Orange',
    'Blazed Green' => 'Green',
    'Blck' => 'Black',
    'Blk' => 'Black',
    'Bluberry' => 'Blue',
    'Blue' => 'Blue',
    'Blue Fire' => 'Blue',
    'Blue Metallic' => 'Blue',
    'Blue White' => 'White',
    'Blueberry' => 'Blue',
    'Blueberyy' => 'Blue',
    'Bright White' => 'White',
    'Bronze' => 'Tan',
    'Brown' => 'Tan',
    'Brushed' => 'Silver',
    'Brushed Aluminum' => 'Silver',
    'Burgandy' => 'Red',
    'Burgundy' => 'Red',
    'Cadmium  Yellow' => 'Yellow',
    'Camo' => 'Camo',
    'Camo Gray' => 'Camo',
    'Camo Gre' => 'Camo',
    'Camo Green' => 'Green',
    'Camogreen' => 'Green',
    'Camp Green' => 'Green',
    'Candy Burnt Orange' => 'Orange',
    'Candy Cascade Blue' => 'Blue',
    'Candy Lime Green' => 'Green',
    'Candy Persimmon Red' => 'Red',
    'Candy Red' => 'Red',
    'Carbon' => 'Grey',
    'Carbon Gray' => 'Grey',
    'Carbon Metallic' => 'Silver',
    'Charcoal Silver' => 'Silver',
    'Cherry' => 'Red',
    'Chili Pepper' => 'Red',
    'Chrome' => 'Silver',
    'Cognac' => 'Tan',
    'Comp Silver' => 'Silver',
    'Competition Silver' => 'Silver',
    'Cool Blue Pearl' => 'Blue',
    'Cool Candy Red' => 'Red',
    'Copper' => 'Tan',
    'Copper Metallic' => 'Tan',
    'Crimson' => 'Red',
    'Crimson Metallic' => 'Red',
    'Custom' => '',
    'Dark Grey' => 'Grey',
    'Dark Metallic Green' => 'Green',
    'Dark Red Metallic' => 'Red',
    'Dark Royal Red' => 'Red',
    'Daytona Blue' => 'Blue',
    'Deep Blue' => 'Blue',
    'Ebony' => 'Black',
    'Ember Red Sunglow' => 'Red',
    'Flat Black' => 'Black',
    'Flat Ebony' => 'Black',
    'Galv' => '',
    'Gldn Grn' => 'Green',
    'Gold' => 'Gold',
    'Granite Gray' => 'Grey',
    'Graphite' => 'Grey',
    'GRAPHITE CRYSTAL' => 'Grey',
    'GRAY' => 'Gray',
    'GRAY BLUE METALLIC' => 'Blue',
    'GRAYSTONE' => 'Grey',
    'GREEN' => 'Green',
    'GREY' => 'Grey',
    'HAV RED' => 'Red',
    'HAVASU PEARL RED' => 'Red',
    'HONDA PHANTOM CAMO' => 'Camo',
    'HUNTER GREEN' => 'Green',
    'IMPACT BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'INDY RED' => 'Red',
    'INTENSE RED' => 'Red',
    'INTENSE RED PEARL' => 'Red',
    'KEY LIME' => 'Green',
    'LAVA RED' => 'Red',
    'LIGHT GRE' => 'Green',
    'LIGHT GREY' => 'Grey',
    'LIGHT SILVER METALLIC' => 'Silver',
    'LIGUID GRAPHITE' => 'Grey',
    'LIME' => 'Green',
    'LIME GREEN' => 'Green',
    'LIME GREEN ' => 'Green',
    'LIME GRN' => 'Green',
    'LIQUID GRAPHITE' => 'Grey',
    'LIQUID SILVER' => 'Silver',
    'MAGNESIUM' => 'Silver',
    'MAGNESIUM METALLIC' => 'Silver',
    'MALDIVES BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'MALDIVES GREE' => 'Green',
    'MAROON' => 'Red',
    'MATTE BLACK' => 'Black',
    'MATTE BLACK METALLIC' => 'Black',
    'MATTE GRAY' => 'Grey',
    'MATTE GREY' => 'Grey',
    'MATTE SILVER' => 'Silver',
    'MATTE TITAN' => 'Silver',
    'MATTE WHITE LIGHTNING' => 'White',
    'MERLO' => 'Silver',
    'METALLIC' => 'Silver',
    'METALLIC BLACK' => 'Black',
    'METALLIC BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'METALLIC FLAT RAW GRAYSTO' => 'Silver',
    'METALLIC GRAYSTONE' => 'Silver',
    'METALLIC IMPERIAL BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'METALLIC MATTE CARBON GRA' => 'Silver',
    'METALLIC PHANTOM SILVER' => 'Silver',
    'METALLIC SILVER' => 'Silver',
    'METALLIC SPARK BLACK' => 'Black',
    'MOSSY OA' => 'Camo',
    'MOSSY OAK' => 'Camo',
    'MOSSY OAK BREAK-UP' => 'Camo',
    'MOSSY OAK CAMO' => 'Camo',
    'MULTI' => '',
    'NUCLEAR SUNSET' => 'Orange',
    'null' => '',
    'OLIVE' => 'Green',
    'ORANGE' => 'Orange',
    'ORANGE BURST' => 'Orange',
    'ORANGE-MATT' => 'Orange',
    'ORBITAL BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'P.P. CAMO' => 'Camo',
    'PASSION RED' => 'Red',
    'PEARL BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'PEARL CRYSTAL WHITE' => 'White',
    'PEARL RED' => 'Red',
    'PEARL STARDUST WHITE' => 'White',
    'PEARL WHI' => 'White',
    'PEARL WHITE' => 'White',
    'PEARL WHT' => 'White',
    'PERSIMMON RED' => 'Red',
    'PEWTER' => 'Grey',
    'PHANTOM' => 'Camo',
    'PHANTOM BLACK' => 'Black',
    'PHANTOM CAMO' => 'Camo',
    'PINEAPPLE' => 'Yellow',
    'PINK' => 'Red',
    'POLARIS P' => '',
    'POLARIS PURSUIT CAMO' => 'Camo',
    'PURPLE' => 'Purple',
    'PURSUIT CAMO' => 'Camo',
    'RACING BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'RADICAL WHITE' => 'White',
    'Rapid Red' => 'Red',
#N/A
    'REALTREE' => 'Camo',
    'REALTREE AP HD W' => 'Camo',
    'REALTREE APG HD' => 'Camo',
    'REALTREE EXTRA' => 'Camo',
    'REALTREE EXTRA CAMO' => 'Camo',
    'REALTREE XTRA' => 'Camo',
    'REALTREE XTRA CAMO' => 'Camo',
    'REALTREE XTRA GREEN CAMO' => 'Green',
    'RED' => 'Red',
    'RED GREEN' => 'Red',
    'RED HOT SUNGLOW' => 'Red',
    'RED KHAKI' => 'Red',
    'RED PEARL' => 'Red',
    'RED USED TO BE WHITE' => 'Red',
    'RED W' => 'Red',
    'REDDISH COPPER' => 'Red',
#N/A
    'ROOT BEER' => 'Tan',
    'ROSEWOOD BROWN' => 'Tan',
    'SAGE GRE' => 'Green',
    'SAGE GREEN' => 'Green',
    'SALVAGE' => '',
    'SCARLET RED' => 'Red',
    'SE TRI-COLOR' => '',
    'SILVER' => 'Silver',
    'SILVER DENIM' => 'Blue',
    'SILVER METALLIC' => 'Silver',
    'SILVER SATIN' => 'Silver',
    'SILVER-BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'SL' => '',
    'SOLAR RED' => 'Red',
    'SPARK BLACK' => 'Black',
    'SPARTAN RED' => 'Red',
    'SPECTRA O' => '',
    'SPECTRA ORANGE' => 'Orange',
    'STARDUST SILVER' => 'Silver',
    'STARDUST WHITE' => 'White',
    'STEALTH BLACK' => 'Black',
    'STEEL BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'STEEL BLUE W' => 'Blue',
    'STEEL GREY' => 'Grey',
    'STONE GRAY' => 'Grey',
    'SUNBEAM RED' => 'Red',
    'SUNSET RE' => 'Red',
    'SUNSET RED' => 'Red',
    'SUPER BLA' => '',
    'SUPER BLACK' => 'Black',
    'SUPER GRAPHITE' => 'Grey',
    'TAN' => 'Tan',
    'TEAL GREEN' => 'Green',
    'TEAM YAMAHA BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'TIMBERLINE' => 'Grey',
    'TIMBERLINE GREEN' => 'Green',
    'TITANIUM' => 'Silver',
    'TITANIUM M' => 'Silver',
    'TITANIUM MATTE METAL' => 'Silver',
    'TITANIUM MATTE METALLIC' => 'Silver',
    'TITANIUM METALLIC' => 'Silver',
    'TRAIL BLACK PEARL' => 'Black',
    'TRUE TIMBER XD3 CAMO' => 'Camo',
    'TURBO SIL' => 'Silver',
    'TURBO SILVER' => 'Silver',
    'ULTRA BLUE METALLIC' => 'Blue',
    'VANILLA' => 'White',
    'VANILLA WHITE' => 'White',
    'VELOCITY BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'VIPER RED' => 'Red',
    'VOODOO B' => '',
    'VOODOO BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'WHI' => 'White',
    'WHITE' => 'White',
    'WHITE ' => 'White',
    'WHITE BLUE' => 'White',
    'WHITE GREEN' => 'Green',
    'WHITE LIGH' => 'White',
    'WHITE LIGHTNING' => 'White',
    'WHITE PEARL' => 'White',
    'WHITE-DELUXE' => 'White',
    'WHT' => 'White',
    'YACHT BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'YAMAHA BLUE' => 'Blue',
    'YAMAHA YELLOW' => 'Yellow',
    'YELLOW' => 'Yellow',
    'YELLOW ' => 'Yellow',
    'YELLOW METAL' => 'Yellow',
    'YELLOW SILVER BLACK' => 'Yellow',
    );
if (isset($color[$value])) return $color[$value];
return $value;
}

?>
```

Comment: You can use regular expressions to match colors, but what if colors intersect? Like `Yellowstone Red`, it has `Yellow` and `Red` in it. It's likely to match "Yellow", while the color is actually red. So any kind of automated process will not be fool-proof like what you have now.

Comment: You can use REGEX, and check for a blue variation like this:
`/blue/`super simple.

Comment: I'm ok with it not being a perfect solution at this point because at least it will be manageable.

So is this what you mean will work?  I'm sorry but I know zero PHP

`<?php
function my_color($value) {
  $color = array(
  '/blue/' => 'Blue'
  '/yellow/' => 'Yellow'
    );
if (isset($color[$value])) return $color[$value];
return $value;
}

?>`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function here.It is not of complete help but though u can use it.

```
$a = checkColor('LIGHT SILVER METALLIC');

function checkColor($value){

    //You can add more colors here
    $colors = ['Blue', 'White', 'Orange', 'Green', 'Black', 'Silver'];

    foreach ($colors as $color) {
        if (stripos($value, $color) !== false) {
            $result = $color;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!empty($result))
        return $result;
}
```

So, when you pass your cars color in the function above, it checks for the substring and if present returns accordingly..
But though for colors like aluminium, aqua, brushed I don't see any way around to assign to your own colors..

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested here is the final function that I got to work. It is case in-sensitive and will check if the root word exists as a partial match.

```
    <?php
function my_condition($value) {
  $condition = array(
    'Cons' => 'Used',
    );
  if (isset($condition[$value])) return $condition[$value];
  return $value;
};
function my_color( $original ) {

    $colors = array(
                    'yellow'     => 'Yellow', 
                    'white'     => 'White', 
                    'silver'     => 'Silver', 
                    'blue'         => 'Blue', 
                    'black'     => 'Black', 
                    'orange'     => 'Orange', 
                    'green'     => 'Green',
                    'tan'         => 'Tan', 
                    'red'         => 'Red', 
                    'camo'         => 'Camo', 
                    'grey'         => 'Grey', 
                    'gold'         => 'Gold', 
                    'gray'         => 'Gray', 
                    'grey'          => 'Gray',
                    'purple'     => 'Purple', 
                    'maroon'    => 'Red',
                    'brown'     => 'Tan',
                    'aqua'      => 'Blue',
                    'blk'       => 'Black',
                    'slv'       => 'Silver',
                    'bronze'    => 'Tan',
                    'copper'    => 'Tan',
                    'crimson'   => 'Red',
                    'chili'     => 'Red',
                    'ebony'     => 'Black',
                    'lime'      => 'Green',
                    'mossy'     => 'Camo',
                    'pewter'    => 'Grey',
                    'graphite'  => 'Grey',
                    'vanilla'   => 'White',
                    'titanium'  => 'Silver',
                    'sage g'    => 'Green',
                    'aluminum'  => 'Silver',
                    'black/'    => 'Black',
                    'raven'     => 'Black',
                    'repsol'    => 'Orange',
                    'burgandy'  => 'Red',
                    'cherry'    => 'Red',
                    'carbon'    => 'Black',
                    'olive'     => 'Green',


    );

    $return = 'unknown';
    foreach($colors as $matching_color => $common_color)
     if(strpos(strtolower($original) , strtolower($matching_color)) !== false)
        $return = $common_color;

    return $return;
}

?>
```